# Query to update the data based on value of some other column in same table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table  A  which column as

1. id - which is a sequence
2. type
3. group

i want to update column **GROUP** by following below logic
if `type  =  1` then update group column as constant value let say `'10'` until it finds `'1'` next time .
If it find next time `'1'` then update group as `'11'` and so on ...
please find below example for reference

example

[image]

Can anyone help with  query .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumulative approach :

```
update a
     set group = ( 
                  with my_cte as (
                       select a.*, 
                              sum(case when type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as new_group
                       from a;
                    )
                  select new_group from my_cte where a.id = my_cte.id 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set group = (select count(*) + 9
                 from t t2
                 where t2.id <= t.id and t2.type = 1
                ) ;
```